# OpenGL ES 2 not rendering anything

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es-2.0

The code is based on the template by Visual Studio 2019. Only the background color is drawn but not the triangle. I tried to change the background color as the `engine_draw_frame()` is called by changing the clearcolor dynamically and the background does change. I have tried to use vbo by generating a buffer, binding it and copying the data to the buffer using `glBufferData`, but still no triangle is rendered.

Then I tried with using es1 api like glVertexPointer instead in the same position and the triangle is drawn. Is there anything wrong with the es2 api calls?

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>

#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "AndroidProject1.NativeActivity", __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGW(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "AndroidProject1.NativeActivity", __VA_ARGS__))


GLuint fragShader, vertShader, program;
void create_shaders(void)
{
    static const char* fragShaderText =
        "precision mediump float;\n"
        "void main() {\n"
        "   gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n";
    static const char* vertShaderText =
        "attribute vec4 pos;\n"
        "void main() {\n"
        "   gl_Position = pos;\n"
        "}\n";

    GLint stat;

    fragShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragShader, 1, (const char**)&fragShaderText, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragShader);
    glGetShaderiv(fragShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &stat);
    if (!stat) {
        printf("Error: fragment shader did not compile!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    vertShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertShader, 1, (const char**)&vertShaderText, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertShader);
    glGetShaderiv(vertShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &stat);
    if (!stat) {
        printf("Error: vertex shader did not compile!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, fragShader);
    glAttachShader(program, vertShader);
    glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "pos");
    glLinkProgram(program);  /* needed to put attribs into effect */

    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &stat);
    if (!stat) {
        char log[1000];
        GLsizei len;
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program, 1000, &len, log);
        printf("Error: linking:\n%s\n", log);
        exit(1);
    }

    glUseProgram(program);
}

struct saved_state {
    float angle;
    int32_t x;
    int32_t y;
};

struct engine {
    struct android_app* app;

    ASensorManager* sensorManager;
    const ASensor* accelerometerSensor;
    ASensorEventQueue* sensorEventQueue;

    int animating;
    EGLDisplay display;
    EGLSurface surface;
    EGLContext context;
    int32_t width;
    int32_t height;
    struct saved_state state;
};

static int engine_init_display(struct engine* engine) {
    const EGLint attribs[] = {
        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_NONE
    };
    EGLint w, h, format;
    EGLint numConfigs;
    EGLConfig configs[2];
    EGLSurface surface;
    EGLContext context;

    EGLDisplay display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

    eglInitialize(display, 0, 0);

    eglGetConfigs(display, configs, 2, &numConfigs);
    eglChooseConfig(display, attribs, configs, 2, &numConfigs);

    ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(engine->app->window, 0, 0, format);
    create_shaders();
    surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, configs[0], engine->app->window, NULL);
    eglBindAPI(EGL_OPENGL_ES_API);
    context = eglCreateContext(display, configs[0], NULL, NULL);

    if (eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context) == EGL_FALSE) {
        LOGW("Unable to eglMakeCurrent");
        return -1;
    }
    eglSwapInterval(display, 0);
    eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_WIDTH, &w);
    eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_HEIGHT, &h);

    engine->display = display;
    engine->context = context;
    engine->surface = surface;
    engine->width = w;
    engine->height = h;
    engine->state.angle = 0;

    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_FASTEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    return 0;
}

static void engine_draw_frame(struct engine* engine) {
    if (engine->display == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    static double r = 0;
    r += 0.01;
    glViewport(0, 0, engine->width, engine->height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    GLfloat vTriangle[] = { 0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
                        -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                        0.5, -0.5, 0.0 };
    GLfloat cTriangle[] = { 0.9, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vTriangle);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    eglSwapBuffers(engine->display, engine->surface);
}

static void engine_term_display(struct engine* engine) {
    if (engine->display != EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
        eglMakeCurrent(engine->display, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_CONTEXT);
        if (engine->context != EGL_NO_CONTEXT) {
            eglDestroyContext(engine->display, engine->context);
        }
        if (engine->surface != EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
            eglDestroySurface(engine->display, engine->surface);
        }
        eglTerminate(engine->display);
    }
    engine->animating = 0;
    engine->display = EGL_NO_DISPLAY;
    engine->context = EGL_NO_CONTEXT;
    engine->surface = EGL_NO_SURFACE;
}

static int32_t engine_handle_input(struct android_app* app, AInputEvent* event) {
    struct engine* engine = (struct engine*)app->userData;
    if (AInputEvent_getType(event) == AINPUT_EVENT_TYPE_MOTION) {
        engine->state.x = AMotionEvent_getX(event, 0);
        engine->state.y = AMotionEvent_getY(event, 0);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void engine_handle_cmd(struct android_app* app, int32_t cmd) {
    struct engine* engine = (struct engine*)app->userData;
    switch (cmd) {
    case APP_CMD_SAVE_STATE:
        engine->app->savedState = malloc(sizeof(struct saved_state));
        *((struct saved_state*)engine->app->savedState) = engine->state;
        engine->app->savedStateSize = sizeof(struct saved_state);
        break;
    case APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW:
        if (engine->app->window != NULL) {
            engine_init_display(engine);
            engine_draw_frame(engine);
        }
        break;
    case APP_CMD_TERM_WINDOW:
        engine_term_display(engine);
        break;
    case APP_CMD_GAINED_FOCUS:
        if (engine->accelerometerSensor != NULL) {
            ASensorEventQueue_enableSensor(engine->sensorEventQueue,
                engine->accelerometerSensor);
            ASensorEventQueue_setEventRate(engine->sensorEventQueue,
                engine->accelerometerSensor, (1000L / 60) * 1000);
        }
        break;
    case APP_CMD_LOST_FOCUS:
        if (engine->accelerometerSensor != NULL) {
            ASensorEventQueue_disableSensor(engine->sensorEventQueue,
                engine->accelerometerSensor);
        }
        engine->animating = 0;
        engine_draw_frame(engine);
        break;
    }
}

void android_main(struct android_app* state) {
    struct engine engine;

    memset(&engine, 0, sizeof(engine));
    state->userData = &engine;
    state->onAppCmd = engine_handle_cmd;
    state->onInputEvent = engine_handle_input;
    engine.app = state;
    engine.sensorManager = ASensorManager_getInstance();
    engine.accelerometerSensor = ASensorManager_getDefaultSensor(engine.sensorManager,
        ASENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    engine.sensorEventQueue = ASensorManager_createEventQueue(engine.sensorManager,
        state->looper, LOOPER_ID_USER, NULL, NULL);

    if (state->savedState != NULL) {
        engine.state = *(struct saved_state*)state->savedState;
    }

    engine.animating = 1;
    while (1) {
        int ident;
        int events;
        struct android_poll_source* source;

        while ((ident = ALooper_pollAll(engine.animating ? 0 : -1, NULL, &events,
            (void**)&source)) >= 0) {
            if (source != NULL) {
                source->process(state, source);
            }
            if (ident == LOOPER_ID_USER) {
                if (engine.accelerometerSensor != NULL) {
                    ASensorEvent event;
                    while (ASensorEventQueue_getEvents(engine.sensorEventQueue,
                        &event, 1) > 0) {
                        LOGI("accelerometer: x=%f y=%f z=%f",
                            event.acceleration.x, event.acceleration.y,
                            event.acceleration.z);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (state->destroyRequested != 0) {
                engine_term_display(&engine);
                return;
            }
        }

        if (engine.animating) {
            engine.state.angle += .01f;
            if (engine.state.angle > 1) {
                engine.state.angle = 0;
            }
            engine_draw_frame(&engine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);` -> `gl_Position = pos;`

Comment: i forgot to change the back :( but still dont works

Comment: Try passing `EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION` to attrib_list to specify you want ES 2. See: https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglCreateContext.xhtml